# What do the terms online and offline refer to in 3D reconstruction in Computer Vision?

Tags: computer-vision, definition, 3d-reconstruction

I have been working on 3D reconstructions from RGB-D cameras recently. I have seen those terms before (online and offline reconstruction) but I always thought they were referring to:

online reconstruction: Real-Time reconstruction, the reconstruction is made as it gets data.

offline reconstruction: You first capture the images and later make the reconstruction.

But now I’m having second thought about it and I can’t find a clarifying explanation.

Comment: You are correct. Usually offline refers to whatever optimization that you can't run in real-time, but that can result in higher accuracy. Online is whatever estimation can be done in real-time, that you can sometimes update with information from off-line processes that you have going on.

Comment: @Ash thanks for your answer!!